Pagination in Salesforce Global Search Results Page
I have implemented External Data Source with a Custom Adapter to display search results from my external application. But I can see a maximum of only 10 records and Salesforce does not show a Next page button or ">" button to view the next set of records.
Is there a way to enable this? Do I have to implement this myself?

If the default pagination controls (like the "Next" button) are not available, you may need to implement them yourself.
Create a custom Lightning Web Component (LWC) that handles pagination logic. This component can include buttons for navigating through pages and displaying the results accordingly.
Use the lightning-button base component for navigation controls and manage the state of the pagination (e.g., isLastPage property) to enable or disable buttons as needed.

Can the default pagination be enabled? Or does it show up automatically?

Default pagination in Salesforce is enabled by default and shows up automatically.
